# Generic Host Process for Win32/No Internet Connection

Tags: windows-xp, networking, network-adapter

A friend has asked me to look at his machine.  It is XP SP3, with 2 NIC cards.

I found that the machine had some Malware on it, which I removed with MalwareBytes.

However, the machine still will not connect to the Internet.  It doesn't seem to recognize when you plug into the first network card.  When you plug into the second, it appears to get a DHCP address, and says "Connected" but cannot get out to the Internet.

Occassionally, a "Generic Host Process for Win32" error pops up, saying that svchost has crashed.  I am not sure that it is directly connected, but it does appear to happen shortly after trying to connect to the Internet, or trying a "Repair" on the network connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is related. the XP Internet Firewall and Connection Sharing service runs using a "Generic Host Process for Win32" and svchost is a "service host" wrapper for system components. so it's quite likely that is where the malware was injecting itself to take over the internet connection. and it appears that while the program killed the rouge code it did not fix the winsock layer or the LSP provider that got corrupted by the malware.

you could try doing a winsock fix, you do need to be longed in as a local admin to do this

Go to the Command Prompt then in there type in "netsh int ip reset reset.txt" with out the quotes and hit enter. in most versions of xp it won't show anything if it worked, only if it hit an error.

next you want to type in "netsh winsock reset" and hit enter, then when it says to reboot the computer. that should reset the winsock layer back to defaults which may help.